# textbox cannot show english numbers in .Net winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

All of integers in my form are shown in Persian. I also changed the CurrentInputLanguage using System.Globalization.CultureInfo to English and now all typed characters are in English except numbers. Numbers are still displayed in Persian. The RiaghtToLeft property of the textbox are "no".
Do you have any suggestion??

Comment: CurrentInputLanguage only affects the keyboard.  You need to change the UI thread's CurrentCulture.  Difficult to avoid problems with that at least until .NET 4.5's DefaultThreadCurrentCulture

Comment: Thanks Hans! so you suggest to migrate to .net 4.5, I cannot migrate because I use many other components which may have problem with other versions of .Net

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to invariant
in your form constructor
code:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace UICulture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it in the form constructor creates the illusion that it only affects the form.  It doesn't, every window will be affected.  This belongs in the Main() method.